# Unable to create quarkus project on intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, quarkus

Getting the following error:

Initialization failed for 'https://code.quarkus.io' Please check URL, network and proxy settings.  Error message: Cannot download 'https://code.quarkus.io/api/extensions': code.quarkus.io

[image]

Can't figure out where to start with this issue

Comment: Ensure that proxy is properly configured under `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy` Check the idea.log file to get a complete error stack trace. (Help | Show Log in ... | open idea.log | scroll till the end | reproduce the problem)

Comment: To debug connectivity problem you can add `com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests`, `#com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests`, `com.intellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy`, `#com.intellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy` under `Help | Diagnostic Tools | Debug Log Settings` and restart the IDE. Each option must be added on a new line.